# Hide element if it has an attribute value within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I'm trying to achieve is hiding specific divs if it's specified attribute matches a value within an array.

The information being used will be dynamic and the divs that need to hide may change. Therefore it has to be extensible.

What I have so far is grabbing the attributes and putting them into an array. Then I'm matching what was put into that array against another array that specifies what divs will need to hide. If a divs attribute matches hide that div otherwise let the div render.

Right now I'm getting an all or none on hiding the divs.

Here is the code

```js
var matching = ['2', '3'];
var mids = [];


$('.merch-tile').each(function(i, e) {
  mids.push($(e).attr('m_mid'));
});
//alert(mids);


for (var c1 = 0; c1 < mids.length; c1++) {

  //alert('running');
  var nm_arg = matching[c1];

  //alert('still running');

  if ($.inArray(nm_arg, mids) === -1)
    $('.merch-tile').hide();

  alert('something matches');

}

$(document.body).append(mids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="1">Tile 1</div>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="2">Tile 2</div>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="3">Tile 3</div>
```

Comment: `$('.merch-tile').hide();` should be `$('.merch-tile[m_mid="'+nm_arg+'"]').hide();`

Comment: You shouldn't use custom attributes. Use `data-mid` instead of `m_mid`.

Comment: Tried adding that snippet to the fiddle doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Expanding on Rolyataylor2, the entire script can be condensed to `matching.forEach(function(e) { $('[m_mid=' + e + ']').hide() })`, provided something is setting the matching array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
var matching = ['2', '3'];  

$('.merch-tile').filter(function (i, e) {
    return matching.indexOf($(this).attr('m_mid')) > -1
}).hide();
```

```js
var matching = ['2', '3'];

$('.merch-tile').filter(function (i, e) {
    return matching.indexOf($(this).attr('m_mid')) > -1
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="1">Tile 1</div>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="2">Tile 2</div>
<div class="merch-tile" m_mid="3">Tile 3</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for also short and sweet thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `mids` array. Just loop over the DOM elements, testing if the attribute is in the array.

I also don't understand `$(document.body).append(mids)` at the end -- `mids` is not HTML, it's an array.

I've also replaced your custom attribute with `data-mid`. `data-XXX` attributes are reserved for the programmer to use as extensions.

If you want to hide the DIVs that **are** in the array, you should test `!= -1`, not `== -1`.

```js
var matching = ['2', '3'];
var something_matches = false;

$('.merch-tile').each(function() {
  if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-mid'), matching) != -1) {
    $(this).hide();
    something_matches = true;
  }
});

if (something_matches) {
  alert('something matches');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="merch-tile" data-mid="1">Tile 1</div>
<div class="merch-tile" data-mid="2">Tile 2</div>
<div class="merch-tile" data-mid="3">Tile 3</div>
```

Beware of using `.data('mid')` instead of `.attr('data-mid')`. `.data()` returns the value as an integer, because an attribute value that's valid JSON is parsed as JSON, but `matching` contains strings.

Comment: The $(document.body).append(mids) is just a test that the values are being inserted into the array to make sure things were working how I was expecting them to.

Comment: Most people use `console.log()` for stuff like that.

Comment: This is doing the opposite of what I was intending.

Comment: Your code hides it if `$.inArray` returns `-1`, which means it's not in the array.

Comment: I reversed the test. Apparently your own code also did the opposite of what you were intending, and I based my code on that.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your code :

```
if ($.inArray(nm_arg, mids) === -1)
    $('.merch-tile').hide(); // Look at here,you hide all, because of your have class name

alert('something matches');
```